# Parent not flex, but children appears flex

Tags: javascript, html, css

it's a beginner question, but I cannot figure out...
Below I have one div, a grey area. For a small shooting game, I appendchild() 2 children.
My children appears as flex (side to side) instead of supperposing as requested by javascript code below :

```js
let cadre_Jeu = document.querySelector('.cadre_Jeu');

let h_cadre = cadre_Jeu.offsetHeight;
let w_cadre = cadre_Jeu.offsetWidth;
let h_pistol = 150;
let w_pistol = h_pistol * 0.72;
//test1
let pistol = document.createElement('img');
pistol.id = 'pistol';
pistol.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/200';
pistol.style.height = h_pistol + 'px';
pistol.style.width = w_pistol + 'px';

cadre_Jeu.appendChild(pistol);
pistol.style.position = 'relative';
pistol.style.left = w_cadre / 2 - w_pistol / 2 + 'px';
pistol.style.top = h_cadre / 2 - h_pistol / 2 + 'px';
//test1 end
//test2
let pistol2 = document.createElement('img');
pistol2.id = 'pistol2';
pistol2.src = 'https://via.placeholder.com/200';
pistol2.style.height = h_pistol + 'px';
pistol2.style.width = w_pistol + 'px';

cadre_Jeu.appendChild(pistol2);
pistol2.style.position = 'relative';
pistol2.style.left = w_cadre / 2 - w_pistol / 2 + 'px';
pistol2.style.top = h_cadre / 2 - h_pistol / 2 + 'px';
//test2 end
```

```css
.cadre_Jeu {
  height: 500px;
  width: 50%;
  background-color: #555;
  border: solid black 2px;
  cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div class="cadre_Jeu"></div>
```

I don't understand why the second child is taking reference on the first one, do you have any idea ?

Comment: What do you mean by "supperposing"? Do mean "on top of each other"? Something else?

Comment: Yes, here is to explain my issue, in my real case, my second img is below the 1st one, but it is offset of the width of the 1st img compare to the position I requested by left and top properties
Here I mean on top of each other for the example below

Comment: Have you tried position of `absolute` for your pistols?

Comment: With absolute it is working, but I wanted to refer on the grey square, that's why I'm using relative property
If no other choice I could use absolute, but I think there could be a way doing both

Comment: I also added a solution if you want to keep the position relative then you can follow it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `<img>` elements are inline elements. You need to change the `position` to `absolute` to get that behavior.

```
pistol.style.position = 'absolute';
```

And also if you want to keep the position relative then subtract the pistol width from the left property of the 2nd pistol like below and it will work too:

```
pistol2.style.left = (w_cadre / 2 - w_pistol / 2) - w_pistol + 'px';
```

```js
let cadre_Jeu = document.querySelector('.cadre_Jeu');

let h_cadre = cadre_Jeu.offsetHeight;
let w_cadre = cadre_Jeu.offsetWidth;
let h_pistol = 150;
let w_pistol = h_pistol * 0.72;
//test1
let pistol = document.createElement('img');
pistol.id = 'pistol';
pistol.src = 'chuck_game.png';
pistol.style.height = h_pistol + 'px';
pistol.style.width = w_pistol + 'px';


cadre_Jeu.appendChild(pistol);
pistol.style.position = 'absolute';
pistol.style.left = w_cadre / 2 - w_pistol / 2 + 'px';
pistol.style.top = h_cadre / 2 - h_pistol / 2 + 'px';
//test1 end
//test2
let pistol2 = document.createElement('img');
pistol2.id = 'pistol2';
pistol2.src = 'chuck_game.png';
pistol2.style.height = h_pistol + 'px';
pistol2.style.width = w_pistol + 'px';


cadre_Jeu.appendChild(pistol2);
pistol2.style.position = 'absolute';
pistol2.style.left = w_cadre / 2 - w_pistol / 2 + 'px';
pistol2.style.top = h_cadre / 2 - h_pistol / 2 + 'px';
//test2 end
```

```css
.cadre_Jeu {
    height: 500px;
    width: 50%;
    background-color: #555;
    border: solid black 2px;
    cursor: crosshair;
}
```

```html
<div class="cadre_Jeu"></div>
```

Comment: With display block, they align now vertically but still not superpozed, thanks for reminder on inline block !

Comment: For that you need ```position: absolute;``` and you can use ```z-index``` to bring one on top of another. The answer is updated.

Comment: I also added a solution if you want to keep the position relative then you can follow it.